# Not able to drag my transparent window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, transparent, nsview

For my OSX application. I have a main window with some output. On a button click a new window will pop up with a drawing on its NSView. I am making this second window transparent by setting its background color as transparent with RGB values as 0.0 and also alpha 0.0. So now my second window just have this random drawing on a transparent background. I have put both the windows in the same xib file.

My problem is that, the transparent window with a drawing that pops up is not draggable. I have overriden mouseDragged: (NSEvent *) in my secondwindow:NSWindow class. But still it is not draggable. This method should work when I try to drag my transparent window using trackpad right ? Any help would be very much appreciated . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Transparent window is not draggable. The only option is to add something like imageview with image, now click and drag the imageview. Total transparent will move.

Comment: But I had already implemented a sample program with just one window instead of two and in that case I was able to drag the transparent window.                                                               In my CustomView in drawRect:(NSRect)rect

    // Draw the blue rectangle.
 NSRect myRect = NSMakeRect(20, 10, 200, 100);
 [[NSColor blueColor] set];
 NSRectFill(myRect);

Comment: post your project somewhere else and send me the link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8ycf32126zksot5/G90l0cW011
This shows the structure of how I implemented  it.

Comment: I thing the first window not getting active after the second window was opened because the first window does not have tittle bar. To check   add the tittle bar and try again.

Comment: But both my windows have title bar. I haven't unchecked Title bar for any.

Comment: OH you mean NSBorderlesswindowmask? I will try it.

Comment: But then the titlebar will appear . I want the whole window to be transparent.